# Regular Expression for &Anyword=

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

What would be a regular expression for **&Anyword=**

I need find the occurrence of this expression and replace it with some other template but i need to retain "Anyword" between "&" and "=".

Comment: you can use `&Anyword=` as your regex, and then just replace it with what ever fits your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find what occurs between the `&` and the `=`, you can use a regex string like `@"&([^\\=]*)="` (i.e. "the characters between `&` and `=` which are, themselves, not the `=` character"). If you also wanted to capture not only `&Anyword=`, but also `?Anyword=`, too, then you might use `@"[&?]([^\\=]*)="`.

When you find a match, you can use the `NSRange` to both identify what the old string was, as well as replace it with something else. For example:

For example, create the regex:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"&([^\\=]*)=" options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(regex, @"Regex failed: %@", error);
```

Now use it to find the string between the `&` and the `=`:

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.apple.com/?device=iPhone&Anyword=true";

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"range = %@", NSStringFromRange(range));

    NSString *foundKey = [string substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"foundKey = %@", foundKey);

    NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"os"];
    NSLog(@"newString = %@", newString);
}];
```

That reports:

```
range = {36, 7}
foundKey = Anyword
newString = http://www.apple.com/?device=iPhone&os=true
```

If you only want to find the first one, you can use `firstMatchInString` rather than going through all of them with `enumerateMatchesInString`, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

---

If this was a URL, though, I might be inclined to get the query portion by just using the `query` method, and then I'd get the various `key=value` components with `componentsSeparatedByString`, and then extract both the `key` and the `value` out with another `componentsSeparatedByString`:

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.apple.com/?device=iPhone&Anyword=true";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSString *query = [url query];
NSLog(@"query = %@", query);
NSArray *parameterArray = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *parameterDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *parameter in parameterArray) {
    NSArray *parameterComponents = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *key = parameterComponents[0];
    NSString *value = parameterComponents[1];

    parameterDictionary[key] = value;
}

NSLog(@"parameterDictionary = %@", parameterDictionary);
```

That would yield:

```
query = device=iPhone&Anyword=true
parameterDictionary = {
    Anyword = true;
    device = iPhone;
}
```

You could then modify that dictionary as you saw fit, and then rebuild the URL, if you needed.

As you can see, you can approach a problem like this using regex, as shown earlier, or by exploding strings into arrays with `componentsSeparatedByString` (and if you want to join them back into strings, you can use `componentsJoinedByString`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work out i believe.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"&Anyword=" options:NSRegularExpressionIgnoreMetacharacters error:&error];
    NSString *reqdString = @"Some string with &Anyword= &Anyword= &Anyword= in it";

    //For a single match
    if ([regex firstMatchInString:reqdString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, reqdString.length)].resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeRegularExpression) {
        [reqdString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Anyword=" withString:@"Replaceemt String"];
    }

    //For mutiple matches
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:reqdString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, reqdString.length)];
    if (numberOfMatches) {
        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfMatches; index ++) {
            //Do your replacement stuff.
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps